# SpannableString within onTextChanged length not correct

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, spannablestring, spannable

I am trying to use the below code to catch when a user enters the @symbol and then higlights
                the proceeding text in the tag_color, no matter where it is typed within the mPostTextView. I am still relatively new to android development so im not to sure
                why I am getting the below error message referring to,  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt:.... as shown below
                which seems to be related to the length of the charAt(start) statement. Can anyone shed light on this?

```
 @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                //@Mentions for tagging user
                if (charSequence.charAt(start) == '@') {
                    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(mPostToText.getText().toString());
                    ForegroundColorSpan foregroundSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.tag_color));
                    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(foregroundSpan, start, spannableStringBuilder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    mPostToText.setText(spannableStringBuilder);

                }
```

this is from the log

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 22 >= length 22
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.charAt(SpannableStringBuilder.java:119)
    at com.tradezapp.tradezapp.gui.activity.CreatePostActivity$CreatePostFragment$2$override.onTextChanged(CreatePostActivity.java:193)
    at com.tradezapp.tradezapp.gui.activity.CreatePostActivity$CreatePostFragment$2$override.access$dispatch(CreatePostActivity.java)
    at com.tradezapp.tradezapp.gui.activity.CreatePostActivity$CreatePostFragment$2.onTextChanged(CreatePostActivity.java)
```

Comment: use charSequence.startsWith("@");

Comment: or  charSequence.charAtIndex(start);

Comment: @ symbol only once.? spannableStringBuilder.length()-1 try this.

Comment: are you want check first char start with @ ?

Comment: I just want the mPostText to recognise anytime the @ symbol is entered along with the preceding text no matter where it be within the EditText view

Answer (score 0):

try this, also check for charSequence lenght,

```
if (charSequence!=null && String.valueOf(charSequence.charAt(count-1)).equal("@")) {
....}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified this better. I want to detect whenever @ is entered no matter where within mPostText not just at the beginning